# "А ты какого цвета, товарищ без билета?"

Tags: этимология

Бывают зайцы серые,
Бывают зайцы белые.
А ты какого цвета,
Товарищ без билета?

Такой стишок в моем детстве был написан в некоторых автобусах. А это я к тому, что интересно, почему безбилетника принято называть зайцем?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Считалось, что безбилетник сидит и трясется, как трусливый заяц.
Но это только одна из версий, широко представленная в интернете.

Я её специально даже подробно не пересказываю, ибо самодостаточно.
Если будет возможность и необходимость - дополню альтернативными.

А вот, даже не пришлось далеко ходить. Обзор "версий" от Ольги Северской. )))

(-----------------)

На этот вопрос нам поможет ответить историко-этимологический справочник «Русская фразеология». По одной из версий, в обороте ехать зайцем есть намек на то, что безбилетный пассажир боится быть пойманным и оштрафованным. В славянском народном сознании заяц – это просто олицетворение трусости. Вспомним хотя бы, что о боящемся чего-то до дрожи человеке говорят: дрожит как заяц. Заяц, кстати, действительно сильно дрожит, когда прячется от надвигающейся опасности. А о человеке, который всего боится, говорят: труслив как заяц. У зайца сердечко маленькое, вот эмоции и бьют через край, заставляя косого дрожать. А в народе о таком «маленьком сердечке» говорят: заячья душа.

Но вернемся к безбилетным пассажирам. По другой версии выражение ехать зайцем отдает должное проворству зайца, его прыткости и прыгучести и происходит от оборотов проскочить зайцем, прошмыгнуть как заяц – пройти незамеченным.

В обиходной речи зайцами стали сначала называть зрителей-безбилетников, ухитрявшихся прошмыгнуть в театр мимо зазевавшихся билетеров. Ну а потом так стали называть и безбилетных пассажиров. О зайцах писал, например, Чехов в рассказе «В вагоне»: «На железных дорогах зайцами называются господа пассажиры, затрудняющие разменом денег не кассиров, а кондукторов. Хорошо, читатель, ездить зайцем! Зайцам полагается по нигде еще не напечатанному тарифу 75% уступки, им не нужно толпиться около кассы, вынимать ежеминутно из кармана билет, с ними кондуктора вежливее и... все что хотите, одним словом!».

Но есть еще и третья версия происхождения оборота ехать зайцем: некоторые ученые предполагают, что это – калька с французского aller (voyager) en lapin, с теми же намеками на трусость и прыткость кролика. Но, спрашивается, зачем нам их кролик, когда у нас есть свой заяц?! Нет, я за русские корни наших отечественных зайцев. А кролики 
пусть за границей ущерб бюджету транспортников наносят...

(-----------------------)

[Почему безбилетников называют зайцами? | 1september.ru](http://rus.1september.ru/view_article.php?ID=200801413)

Answer (score 3):

Еще версии:

1. Жаргон кондукторов: безбилетный пассажир иногда платил небольшие деньги кондуктору, но при этом, не имея билета, должен был сидеть в вагоне очень тихо и никому не показываться на глаза, то есть вести себя подобно зайцу.
2. На первых поездах билеты проверяли на станциях, так что проворные безбилетники могли заранее при торможении поезда у станции спрыгнуть, а затем во время медленного разгона залезть обратно в вагон. Соответственно, такие пассажиры  должны были уметь хорошо бегать и прыгать, как зайцы.

Получается, что "заячье" поведение состоит в следующем: незаметно запрыгнуть и затаиться.